# Cannot find executable for CFBundle (SocialFramework, CertUIFramework, GeoServices)

Tags: ios, xcode, executable, social-framework, cfbundleidentifier

In Xcode, I am getting the following warning messages in the console when I run my code:

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xb64f080 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/SocialFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xb6558f0 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xb6616a0 
</Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

I already know that I can clear all these messages by pressing "reset and content settings" button in the IOS simulator menu. However, it only clears the messages for the first run and they come back to the console after the second run of my code. I am wondering if there is an ultimate solution to clear them all. I just don't want to see them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Reset Content and Settings" solved the problem permanently for me. Are you using Xcode 6?

Comment: I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and receiving this. I actually found the solution and it is gone now.

Comment: Could you please share the solution you found so others can profit from the question too?

Comment: Sure. I will post here once I find the code I used.

Comment: So @MuhsinZahidUgur can you post it now :P?